# Using 'AddThis' to add a 'more' button

Tags: 7

I'm using [AddThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/addthis) to add sharing functionality for my nodes. I setup the tool in 'config' and selected the options I wanted...and it shows up ok. However, I can't figure out how to add the orange 'more' button with the white + sign...[see here for an example](https://www.addthis.com/services) of what I mean by the orange button with the plus sign (it's their favico and also displays on their vertical addthis sharing bar on the left).

I tried [finding it here](https://www.addthis.com/services) but searching for 'more' doesn't find it. So I don't know what it's called. I also tried just adding a bunch more services but that just adds a long horizontal list of buttons.

This more button is great because not only does it allow people to use other services to share things, other than the most common services, but it also shows the number of times the page has been shared!

Anyone know how to add this more button?

Comment: sorry i'd just posted it and didn't realize someone was responding right away. i just undeleted it.

Comment: note: i found that you can add the 'pill_style' to the addthis buttons toolbox but it displays like a long, short button with the word share in it. I'd prefer a box like on the site I linked to (their site!).

Comment: Merci for undeleting! I finished my answer to it (you even got a 2nd answer already ...). Curious about your feedback later on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out you add the orange 'more' services button (with the white plus icon) by using 'compact' as the name of the service in the services list when configuring the display for the AddThis field in your content type.